# ListView does not update with PropertyChanged Event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am working on a WPF application using [This Design Pattern for MVVM](http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html)

I have the following XML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedLimitAmount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat={}{0:$#,#.00}}"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Margin="2,2,2,2"/>
<Button Content="Adjust" 
        FontSize="9"
        Command="{Binding AdjustLimit}"
        Background="Blue" Foreground="White"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
        Height="20" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2,2,2,2"/>
<!--Credit Limit Listview-->
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Limits, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLimit}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,2,2,0">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Account" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Activity}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Credit Limit" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LimitAmount, StringFormat={}{0:$#,#.00}}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

That is bound to this code:

```
Public Class ImportPresenter : ObservableObject
{
    //Credit Limits
    private ObservableCollection<CreditLimitItem> _Limits;
    private CreditLimitItem _SelectedLimit;
    private decimal _SelectedLimitAmount = 0;

    public ObservableCollection<CreditLimitItem> Limits
    {
        get
        {
            return _Limits;
        }
        set
        {
            _Limits = value;
            Debug.Print("Limits Updated");
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Limits");
        }
    }

    public decimal SelectedLimitAmount
    {
        get { return _SelectedLimitAmount; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedLimitAmount = value;
            Debug.Print("Amount Changed");
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedLimitAmount");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Selected Credit Limit
    /// </summary>
    public CreditLimitItem SelectedLimit
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedLimit;
        }
        set
        {
            _SelectedLimit = value;
            SelectedLimitAmount = _SelectedLimit.LimitAmount;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedLimit");
        }
    }

    public ICommand AdjustLimit
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand(UpdateLimit); }
    }

    private void UpdateLimit()
    {
        if(_SelectedLimit != null)
        {
            _SelectedLimit.LimitAmount = _SelectedLimitAmount;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Limits");

            foreach(CreditLimitItem item in Limits)
            {
                Debug.Print(item.LimitAmount.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CreditLimitItem
{

    private int _LimitSequence;
    private short _ActivitySequence;
    private string _Activity;
    private decimal _LimitAmount;
    private DateTime _StartDate;
    private DateTime _EndDate;
    private decimal _NewLimit;

    public int LimitSequence { get => _LimitSequence; set => _LimitSequence = value; }
    public short ActivitySequence { get => _ActivitySequence; set => _ActivitySequence = value; }
    public string Activity { get => _Activity; set => _Activity = value; }
    public decimal LimitAmount { get => _LimitAmount; set => _LimitAmount = value; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get => _StartDate; set => _StartDate = value; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get => _EndDate; set => _EndDate = value; }
    public decimal NewLimit { get => _NewLimit; set => _NewLimit = value; }
    public decimal LimitChange { get => _LimitAmount - _NewLimit; }


    public CreditLimitItem(int sequence, short activitySequence, string activity, decimal amount, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        _LimitSequence = sequence;
        _ActivitySequence = activitySequence;
        _Activity = activity;
        _LimitAmount = amount;
        _StartDate = startDate;
        _EndDate = endDate;
    }
}
```

However, when I update the `TextBox` control, the `ListView` does not refresh on the `PropertyChanged` Event. Am I missing something in my XAML? I should be able to adjust the selected `CreditLimitItem.LimitAmount` in my `TextBox` and the related `ListView` should update after I click on `Adjust`. Not sure why it's not working, though.

Comment: `CreditLimitItem` needs to be an `ObservableObject` and you need to raise property changed on bound values

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless. It has no effect here, and has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: If an object is in an `ObservableCollection` and doesn't implement `INotfityPropertyChanged`, does it not update, even if you raise the `PropertyChangedEvent` on the Bound Getter?

Comment: You'll have to fire a PropertyChanged event for the `CreditLimitItem.LimitAmout` property. That doesn't happen automagically.

Comment: Ah.... so any item in an `ObservableCollection` needs to be an `ObservableObject` and fire off a `PropertyChanged` event?

Comment: Only if it is supposed to inform about value changes :-)

Comment: Just adjusted and it works. Booya! Side-Note: I had VS auto-generate all of those getters/setters, only to re-write them the old way in order to add in the `RaisePropertyChangedEvent`

Comment: slight critique, ObservableCollections should be read only properties. They have change notifications used by the UI. That's why they're "observable".

Comment: Thanks! I'll adjust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class CreditLimitItem should implement INotifyPropertyChanged for that.
When you call `_SelectedLimit.LimitAmount = _SelectedLimitAmount;` nothing happening as LimitAmount setter does not raise the PropertyChanged event.  Note that `RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Limits");` does not have effect at all as Limits are still the same collection.

Comment: Thanks! I had assumed that firing off the `PropertyChanged` event in the `Limits` Property would change the collection. I've adjusted my properties in my `CreditLimitItem` class to implement it and it's working now. Thanks!